# Javascript number comparison with negative value doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I try to compare a negative value with "0" and that doesn't seem to work.

```
var number = Number.parseInt($(this).val());
var min = Number.parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
var max = Number.parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
```

Here's my condition :

```
if (min && $(this).prop('required')) {
    if (number < min) {
        alert('ok');
            fail = true;
    }
}
```

> My min value is 0 and my number is -1.

It never enters the condition. Why?

Comment: *"My min value is 0"* That alone will prevent the condition from succeeding. Maybe you meant `if (!isNaN(min) && ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0` is a [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value. It will never enter the `if` condition if `min` is `0` .

All the following conditions will be sent to else blocks

```
if (false)
if (null)
if (undefined)
if (0)
if (NaN)
if ('')
if ("")
if (``)
```

Since the return value of `parseInt` is either a number or `NaN`, you can use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead:

```
if(!isNaN(min) && $(this).prop('required')) {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `min` is 0, your condition evaluates to `false`. You have two options, one is to check the string value before parsing it:

```
if($(this).attr('min').trim() && $( this ).prop('required')) {
    if (number < min) {
        alert('ok');
        fail = true;
    }
}
```

The other is to check for `NaN` after parsing the number since parsing an empty string will return `NaN`:

```
if(!isNaN(min) && $( this ).prop('required')) {
    if (number < min) {
        alert('ok');
        fail = true;
    }
}
```

```js
console.log('  '.trim() == false);
console.log(!isNaN(Number.parseInt('')) == false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition:

```
if(min && $( this ).prop('required'))
```

Would evaluate to `false` since min has a value of 0 and `0 && anything` would be `false`

Answer (score 0):

(0 && true ) return zero in JavaScript.
see first comment for more details

Comment: This may be a nitpick, but `0 && true` actually returns `0`, not `false`. In this case, the results are the same, because `if` conditions only care whether a value is truthy/falsy, not whether it's the specific value `true` or `false`.